# Can the argument for Switch statement have an expression to eliminate a variable used for comparison?

Tags: c, switch-statement

This program simulates a simple menu driven calculator with +, -, *, and / operations

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    float a = 0, b = 0;
    printf(" Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf(" %f %f",&a ,&b);

    puts(" Enter choice number of operation: ");
    puts(" 1)Addition ");
    puts(" 2)Subtraction ");
    puts(" 3)Multiplication ");
    puts(" 4)Division ");

    flushall();    //To clear the trailing '\n'
    switch( getchar() - 48 )
    {
        case 1: printf("The Sum of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f",a,b,(a+b));
            break;
        case 2: printf("The Difference of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f",a,b,(a-b));
            break;
        case 3: printf("The Product of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f",a,b,(a*b));
            break;
        case 4: if ( b != 0 ) printf("The Quotient of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f",a,b,(a/b));
            else puts("Error, divide by zero not possible.");
            break;
        default: puts("Error, Invalid choice");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it better this way? As I have avoided the usage of a variable, and equivalently described why the program crashes when the last input is not a valid choice, I don't think there is any need to add info about what was entered. It adds an extra variable into the picture.

Comment: Your question needs a bit more explanation !

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/ In switch satements only constant expressions are allowed

Comment: the **cast** is useless before the `getchar()` because it returns **int** as the definition of the function speculates: `int getchar ( void );`

Comment: The layout of the code in the switch is horrid: put the case labels on their own line, and the operational code on its own line, and do this uniformly — unless everything for all cases can be fitted on one line, which isn't the feasible here.  The `getchar() - 48` in the switch 'works', but in general isn't a good idea.  In this context, it more or less detects EOF (it reports "Error, Invalid choice"), but wouldn't work well in general.  Error messages should be reported on standard error (`stderr`); that's what it exists for.

Comment: Also, error messages should identify the problem better than just `invalid choice`; you should show the erroneous input, which you can't do if it has not been captured in a variable.  `int c; switch ((c = getchar()) { case '1': …; case '2': …; case '3': …; case '4': …; default: …; }` would be better.  Note too that the character read by `getchar()` will be the newline after the numbers.  Assuming ASCII encoding is unnecessary (see rewrite), and the notation shown would allow you to process `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'` and `'/'` as well as the numeric encodings for the operators.

Comment: Thanks for info.. I am still new with the Formatting. I don't get the head or tail of it right now. Need help.. Is there a way I can approve somebody else's edit or copy-paste it to the question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on code review.

Comment: I don't know about the conventions followed here. If you do find that it is out of place, let me know how to fix that problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, switch statement can take an expression for the value on which you switch. Your code should work fine, except that getchar() would read the leftover '\n' character from scanf of the operands.

Add another call to getchar() before the switch to read and discard that extra character.

Comment: The extra call to `getchar()` is designed to read the newline that follows the two numbers, or indeed any other character that terminated the numeric input.  Without that, you get the delimiter (usually it'll be a newline).  However, if the input had trailing blanks, it won't help enough — it would be better to use `if (scanf(" %c", &c) == 1) { …process the character read into c with the switch… }`, though the OP is going to great (unportable, unsound) lengths to avoid declaring a variable `c` to hold the input value — a 'penny wise, pound foolish' exercise.

Answer (score 2):

While the code is valid and correct, I'd do the following to make it more readable:

```
switch(getchar()) {
    case '1': // ...
    case '2': // ...
    case '3': // ...
    case '4': // ...
}
```

Or

```
switch(getchar() - '0') {
    case 1: // ...
    case 2: // ...
}
```

This is to avoid using the magic number 48, which may not be understood easily by readers.

Furthermore, you can discard input until the next `\n` using a simple `while` loop:

```
while(getchar() != '\n') ;
```

In addition to the `\n`, this will also read and discard anything *before* the newline.

Comment: There are lot of issues with having code like this please take a look at my answer which is much safer

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that completely.. :p

Comment: @Gopi My point is to avoid using `48`, an unexplained constant, in the code. The trailing new line issue can be easily dealt with using the method described in the accepted answer, or using a method I just edited into my answer.

Comment: And that's not even needed if the program is to perform only one operation and exit.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch ( expression )
```

So you have a valid expression and you can have a expression like you have if you really have a need for something like this.

Else

```
char ch = getchar(); /* or scanf(" %c",&ch); (Better)*/
int a = ch - '0';

switch(a)
{
}
```

Comment: that's what I wanna avoid.. I wanna avoid using an extra variable for it. There you have used two more variables than I have..
Am saving memory as much as I can dude..

Comment: @Adil Cool if you are really worried about memory than you can have a expression in switch() like you have but the problem is getchar() will pick up the newline character left after your first scanf()

Comment: @Adil: the extra variable will allow your code to work sanely.  Not using a variable makes your code brittle — it will fail far too easily, not least because you have to read past the newline left in the input by the first `scanf()` operation.  If your variable is going to occupy megabytes of space, you need to be cautious about creating them.  Single integers aren't going to break the memory bank.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, but if these single variables are allowed loose in a multi threaded environment then they do cause problems. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @Adil: what on earth do you mean?  The local variables in a function are inherently thread-safe (unless you go trying to share them between threads), and if a single `int` overflows your thread stack, you were flying far too close to the sun with your waxen wings.

Comment: @Adil as already told your code in-order to overcome usage of variabled have issue so the safer way to do it is shown by me

Answer (score 1):

For your answer : Yes the **`switch`** can accept an expression in its arguments but it should returns only one of these types `char` `int` `short` `long int` `long long int` it can be also **signed** or **unsigned** !

There is no need to make a cast for the expression `getchar() - 48`  because `getchar()` returns `int` and `48` is an `int` so th result would be an `int`

now after compiling you have to add **3** number one for the variable `a` and the second for the variable `b` and the third for the `switch` statement... for instance

```
$./executable_file 
Enter two numbers: 1 2 3
```

Comment: but i need to show the menu before allowing the user to enter a choice

Comment: you need to show the menu before the expression `scanf` ! Put all the **`puts`** expression **between** the `scanf` and the `switch`, put them all **BEFORE** the `scanf`

Comment: :'( That is so unconvenient

Comment: I think this is the best way ! when you go to the restaurant you read the menu and then you take a choice ! Besides, how can I know which number I need to enter in the input  :)

Comment: Why do you think the `%1f` is a good idea?  It means you can only have a single-digit second operand, which isn't really a good design for a calculator.

Comment: You are Totally right @JonathanLeffler ! Thanks for mentioning that I though it was only for digits !!

Answer (score 0):

#### Switch formatting

This is a suggested formatting of your switch statement.  I disagree with the idea of using `getchar()` in the switch statement (though it is technically legal, it is simply a bad idea in practice), so I've replaced that with `c`:

```
int c;

/* c is set by some input operation.
** It might be char c; if you read its value with scanf(), but it must be int if you use getchar()
*/
switch (c)
{
    case 1:
        printf("The Sum of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f", a, b, (a+b));
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("The Difference of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f", a, b, (a-b));
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("The Product of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f", a, b, (a*b));
        break;
    case 4:
        if (b != 0)
            printf("The Quotient of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f",a, b, (a/b));
        else
            fputs("Error, divide by zero not possible.\n", stderr);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, Invalid choice %c\n", c);
        break;
}
```

Note the use of `break;` after the `default:` label too; it protects you against future additions to the code and is completely uniform.  (The `default:` label does not have to be last, though that is the conventional place for it to go.)  Commas get a space after them; so do `if`, `for`, `while`, `switch`, but function calls do not get a space between the name and the open parenthesis.  You don't normally need a space after an open parenthesis or before a close parenthesis.  Errors are reported to standard error.

Personally, I like the actions of the switch to be indented just one level, not two levels, so I'd use:

```
switch (c)
{
case 1:
    printf("The Sum of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f", a, b, (a+b));
    break;
case 2:
    printf("The Difference of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f", a, b, (a-b));
    break;
case 3:
    printf("The Product of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f", a, b, (a*b));
    break;
case 4:
    if (b != 0)
        printf("The Quotient of %.2f and %.2f is : %.2f",a, b, (a/b));
    else
        fputs("Error, divide by zero not possible.\n", stderr);
    break;
default:
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, Invalid choice %c\n", c);
    break;
}
```

Many people disagree, so you're certainly not under an obligation to do that.

Comment: Sir i think your forgot to mention what `c` is

Comment: @Gopi: I didn't forget; I deliberately left it out as immaterial to the code formatting that I am discussing, as opposed to the 'problem fix' which other answers have given, and which my copious comments on the question and other answers have given.  I've added it now, though, but I've still not coded the fix.

Comment: Domo Arigato.. Nice formatting.. I didn't know about the fputs(..); and fprintf(..); functions. Please do explain them.

Comment: The manual pages will help.  Basically, the `printf("…", …)` function is an alternative to `fprintf(stdout, "…", …)`.  Similarly, but subtly differently, `puts(s)` is equivalent to `fputs(s, stdout); putc('\n', stdout)`; that is, `puts()` writes the string it is given to standard output, followed by a newline, whereas `fputs(s, fp)` writes exactly the string it is given without adding a newline.  The `scanf()` and `fscanf()` functions are parallel to the `printf()` and `fprintf()` function — but `scanf()` reads from standard input, of course.  Etc.